# how to make my created award object become assigned to a car object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and building my first app. I can't figure how to assign a car_id to new instances of awards that get created with the views/awards/new.html.erb file. Can anyone take a look and see where I am going wrong?

awards controller:

```
class AwardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_award, only: [:show]

  def new
    @award = Award.new
  end

  def index
    @awards = Award.all
  end

  def create
    @car = Car.params
    @award = Award.new(award_params)
    @award.save
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

  def set_award
    @award = Award.find(params[:id])
  end

  def award_params
    params.require(:award).permit(:title, :year, :description)
  end
end
```

cars controller

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  def index
    @cars = Car.all
  end

  def create
    @car = Car.new(car_params)
    @car.save
    current_user.cars << @car
    redirect_to current_user, :flash => { :success => "car created!" }
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @car.update(car_params)
    if @car.valid?
      @car.save
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def show
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @car.destroy
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end

  private

  def set_car
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def car_params
    params.require(:car).permit(:make,:model,:year,:color)
  end

end
```

car.rb

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :awards 
end
```

award.rb

```
class Award < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
  has_one :user, through: :cars
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :awards
  resources :cars
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  resources :users
  root 'welcome#home'
  resources :users do
    resources :cars
  end

  resources :cars do
    resources :awards
  end
end
```

@awards form

```
<%= form_for @award do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br>

  <%= f.label :year %>
  <%= f.text_field :year %><br>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %><br>

  <%= f.submit %>

<%end%>
```

I need to be able to assign awards to specific cars, does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Set the car's ID to the award's car ID? Append it to the retrieved car's awards? There are many ways.

Comment: Where would you suggest setting the car's Id to the award's car Id?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/cars/2/awards/new this is the url for the new award form, is there a way to access the 2 in the url and assign it as the car_id for the new award?

Comment: Have you looked to see what parameters are available to you in the awards controller under the cars route? You might want to take a step back and spin through a tutorial real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using nested routes:

> ```
> resources :cars do
>   resources :awards
> end
> ```

Then:

**app/controllers/awards_controller.rb**

```
class AwardsController < ApplicationController
  # add more into the array as you need
  before_action :set_car, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @award = @car.awards.new
  end

  def create
    @award = @car.awards.new(award_params)
    @award.save
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end

  private

  def set_car
    @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  end
end
```

**app/views/awards/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@car, @award] do |f| %>
  ...
```

### Trivia:

- because you are using nested routes, then your links would be something like:

  ```
  <%= link_to 'New Award', new_car_award_path(SOMECAR) %>
  <%= link_to 'Awards', car_awards_path(SOMECAR) %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit Award', edit_car_award_path(SOMECAR, SOMEAWARD) %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete Award', car_award_path(SOMECAR, SOMEAWARD), method: :delete %>
  ```

*...just replace `SOMECAR` and `SOMEAWARD` with a **Car** and **Award** instances respectively, that you want to be in that link.*

### Recommendations:

- handle validations errors. See [tutorial](https://learn.co/lessons/validations-with-form_for-rails)
- If possible, use [shallow nesting](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting)

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! I tried the code you suggested, and got this error:  

'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Car with 'id'=):
  
app/controllers/awards_controller.rb:33:in `set_car'' 

I am looking into the resources you posted now, thanks again!

Comment: @Chris you have to update your `form_for @award` to be `form_for [@car, @award]`

Comment: @Chris MrYoshiji is correct, I forgot to add that part. I'm updating my answer now :)

Comment: @Chris no prob!! :) Good luck further!